# API for Network File System using Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, nfs

We have an use case of downloading a large file hosted on Network File System. That means it will be accessible through nfs://.

I need a Java/Scala library that can access/read/move the file to my local or in HDFS for that matter.

Whatever I have read so far there are issues on API's: 
1. WebNFS changed Yanfs
2. Yanfs has no activity: https://java.net/projects/yanfs/sources/svn/show
3. No maven repository dependency to use in project
4. No Documentation

If programatically (**not by mounting**) I have to access files using Java/Scala what is my best bet!!

Comment: My use case is just copying file exposed by NFS share. Is programatically scp is an option?